# Reactive Forms and Angular Material

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I was working on this form using reactive forms from Angular and everything was working fine but then I started to use Angular Material for radio buttons and the logic that I wrote stoped working.  Any recommendation?
The commented code on the file child.component.html is my original code .

[MY CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-qpulen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code. You have to put formControlName at radio-group so can give values at radio button

```js
 <mat-radio-group
      aria-label="Select an option"
      formControlName="titleAction"
    >
```

Comment: Thanks! the solution was so simple haha